# PHP Code deleting data from MySQL database

Tags: php

Hi I am creating a movies system that you can add edit and delete movies from. I have a webpage a that displays all data from the MySQL database and a edit.php which you enter the movie ID and change the values, thing is when you click Update it removes the data from the mysql database(all but the ID). Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php

session_start();
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if ($username)
  {
    echo "<html><center><font face='arial'><p align=right>Welcome <a href='profile.php'>$username</a>. <a href='login/logout.php'>Logout.</a></p align>";
  }
else
  {
    echo "<html><center><font face='arial'><p align=right><a href=login/index.php>Login</a> or <a href=login/registration/register.php>Sign up!</a></p align>";
  }
echo "<a href='index.php'>Home</a> | <a href='movie-add.php'>Add a movie</a> | <a href='movies.php'>Movies list</a><center></html></font face='arial'>";
echo "<html><br></html>";
echo "<html><br></html>";
echo "<html><br></html>";
echo "<html><center><font face=arial><b>If you made a mistake here you can change the information you entered. </center></b><font face=arial></html>";
echo "<html><br></html>";
echo "<html><br></html>";

if(isset($_POST['update']))
  {
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    if(! $conn)
      {
        die('Something went wrong show this to dylan:'.mysql_error());
      }

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $moviename = $_POST['name']; 
    $movieage = $_POST['age'];
    $moviedate = $_POST['date'];
    $moviedescrip = $_POST['description'];

    $sql = "UPDATE movies " .
      "SET name = '$moviename', " .
      "age = '$movieage', " .
      "date = '$moviedate', " .
      "description = '$moviedescrip' " .
      "WHERE id = $id";

    mysql_select_db('movie_system');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn);
    if(! $retval )
      {
        die('Sorry, could not update the data show this to Dylan: '.mysql_error());
      }

    echo "The values have been changed!";
    mysql_close($conn);
  }
else
  {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
      <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
      <td>Movie ID:</td>
      <td><input name="id" type="text" id="id"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Movie name:</td>
      <td><input name="moviename" type="text" id="name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Movie age rating:</td>
      <td><input name="movieage" type="text" id="age"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Date avilable on DVD:</td>
      <td><input name="moviedate" type="text" id="date"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Description from back of case:</td>
      <td><input name="moviedescrip" type="text" id="description"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update"></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
      <?php
      }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I also asked another question helping me get the code for edit.php:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966956/editing-data-to-a-mysql-database-from-a-php-page)

Comment: You might try outputting your `$_POST` variables before the query to see if they are posted correctly. `echo"<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo"</pre>";` Also try outputting your query to see if it's correct: `echo "<p>".$sql."</p>";`

Comment: Do not use the html tag, like in `echo "<html><br></html>";`. It is meant for the entire page.

Comment: I put it at the top of the webpage and it says this:Array
(
)

Comment: @Joop Edden - What do you mean?

Comment: He means you should only have 1 `<html>` opening tag, it should wrap the entire page, not every line of code

Comment: Please be aware that the `mysql_` set of functions are deprecated and are likely to disappear from future versions of PHP (try looking up mysqli for a similar interface which will remain supported). Also, as you are plugging the form fields straight into the SQL, you open yourself up to what are known as "SQL injection" attacks; someone could deliberately pass you values which would wipe out *all* of your database entries! See http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php for an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input names don't match what you're retrieving with $_POST.

```
<input name="moviename" type="text" id="name">
```

doesn't match:

```
$moviename = $_POST['name'];
```

it should be:

```
$moviename = $_POST['moviename'];
```

id DOES match in both places, which is why the update is successful.

Comment: So what sould the code be then? Thanks for the reply by the way!

Comment: It's in my answer: $moviename = $_POST['moviename'];   (similar change for the others)